# How to bind DataGrid Column to two properties?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 DataGrid tables. If I select the row in the first(Lines), in the second DataGrid(LineProperties) occurs an empty row. I use it to create new object in the data base. The entity has a foreign key (LineId). How to bind the column in the second datagrid to 2 properties at the same time (Line.Id and LineProperties.LineId)? All the objects in the second table must have the same LineId property.

Table 1:

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="AllLines" Margin="5,10,5,5" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lines,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLine, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название линии" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Источник" Binding="{Binding Path=Start}" / >
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Потребитель" Binding="{Binding Path=Finish}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=LineId}"/>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Table 2:

```
<DataGrid  Margin="5,10,5,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding LineProperties, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="N участка" MinWidth="40" Binding="{Binding OrderNumber}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP" MinWidth="30" Binding="{Binding IP}"  />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Длина, м" MinWidth="80" Binding="{Binding Length}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="LineId" Binding="{Binding Path=LineId}"/>
                       <DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Entities:

```
[Table("Lines")]
    public class Line
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RequestId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Start { get; set; }
        public string? Finish { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<LineProperties>? Properties { get; set; }

    }

[Table("LineProperties")]
    public class LineProperties
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int LineId { get; set; }
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public float Length { get; set; }

    }
```

Now I use this approach(loop):

```
foreach (LineProperties lineProperties in LineProperties)
                        {
                            lineProperties.LineId = SelectedLine.Id;
                        }
                       await requestRepository.AddPropertiesAsync(LineProperties);
```

Is there more buitiful solution?

I tried to bind the column to Element(first DataGrid SelectedItem property), but I couldn't get.